# Android Compatibility Test Sutie (CTS) for Jelly Bean: INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT

Tags: android, apk, android-source, cts

I am trying to run the Android Compatibility Test for Jelly Bean. I am currently doing the following to build my Android source and then build the CTS:

```
cd "my-android-source-root"
source build/envsetup.sh
lunch 1
make
make cts
```

I then run the CTS with the following command:

```
cts-tradefed
```

Everything seems OK so far, I then kick off my emulator and see that it is picked up by my CTS instance.

Unfortunately when I try and run a test I get an error when the test tries to install a .apk package.

```
run cts -p android.os
```

This quickly returns the error:

```
E/CtsTest: Failed to install CtsTestStubs.apk. Reason: INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT
```

Have I missed out any steps or have I done anything wrong. If anyone has a working CTS from the AOSP I would be grateful for any advice.

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For me, I found that disabling dexpreopt resulted in installable apk files:

Before running "make cts", do this:

export DISABLE_DEXPREOPT=true

Answer (score 1):

Run below commands in exact sequence to fix this problem:

```
$cd "my-android-source-root"
$source build/envsetup.sh
$lunch 1
$export DISABLE_DEXPREOPT=true
$make -j cts showcommands dist TARGET_PRODUCT=full WITH_DEXPREOPT=false
$make cts
```

Comment: For me, it was `export WITH_DEXPREOPT=false` (followed by `make clean` and `make cts`) that fixed it. I assume `DISABLE_DEXPREOPT=true` does the same thing.